# What is the performance difference between these two mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

```
select sum(a) from tbl1 where id in (1,2,3) (0.1 seconds)
```

and

```
select sum(a) from tbl1 where id in (select id from tbl2) (60 seconds)
```

`select id from tbl2` returns 1,2,3 in 0.001 seconds;

tbl1 has roughly 2.2M entries;

Comment: Missing index in the temporary table.

Comment: you might want to look at the execution plan and see if `(select id from tbl2)` is executed for every id rather than once at the beginning

Comment: Run the query `EXPLAIN select sum(a) from tbl1 where id in (select id from tbl2)`  and post the result.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the helpful comments. It seems that in mysql 5.4 there's a bug that causes high query times when the subquery doesn't have an index on the selected field.

Comment: That is not a bug in mySql; it is a bug in the query design.  Try a google search for the term "table scan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation happens on mysql < 5.5. There seems to be a bug which causes long query time. The solution si to add an index on the tmp2.id or upgrade to higher versions of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`(1,2,3)` is something known already when the code runs, while the second example is a query from another table and it is perfectly normal that the latter takes more. However, 600x slowness needs some further explanation. Without further information of your situation, we can only guess, but the potential problems are as follows:

- there are many ids in the second table and many records in the first table
- the inner query runs for each record of the outer query (highly probable)
- lack of indexes on columns you are using for filtering

If the result of the inner query should be similar to the first example's set, then you might want to separate your queries into two. You could load the ids separately and then use the result for the second query.